# 2008 SQL EXPRESS stored procedures - mine are missing

Tags: database-design, stored-procedures, sql-server-express

I'm using VWD 2008 (SP1) and SQLExpress 2008. I'm creating a database first and then looking at using DynamicDataControls (seem useful and staright foward for a beginner like me).

Within VWD I created a new Dynamic Data Web Application. Then I added a new SQL database item. I noticed that this doesn't include stored procedures or...anything. Is this normal?

I imagine that stored procedures may not be used with the DataControls, but just in case I need ot know, should I be alarmed that stored procedures are not included? How to I include them?

Thanks again for any advice you send my way.

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new database only system objects are included, tables, views, UDFs, triggers, indexes etc etc have to be created by the user

whatever is in the model database will be in any new user generated database. If you want objects to be created every time you create a new database, create them in the model DB first

Take a look at [Automatically create a SQL Server table in a new database.](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/automatically-create-a-sql-server-table-)

Comment: Where do I create a model database? Within VWD or by using the SQL EXPRESS 'manager application' - which seems to have disappeared by the way?

Comment: The model database is one of the system databases, you don't create it,it comes with the installation, master and tempdb are also system databases